# pandas to_datetime: Value error unknown string format. string 01-AUG- 2017 1.03.40.077 AM

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I am working on Windows, and python version is 2.7.

I have a column in a data frame with the following strings

[image]

How can I convert this to datetime?

Comment: Please copy paste part of relevant code. And also add some test date time in the question.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 1):

Use format with [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/)

```
s = "01-AUG- 2017 1.03.40.077 AM"

pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d-%b- %Y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2017-08-01 01:03:40.077000')
```